# How do I create a vision cone that takes into account the size of other turtles?

Tags: netlogo

I was using in-cone, but then I noticed my turtle was "missing" a lot of other turtles inside the cone. From what I understand, this is due to the fact that, for instance:

```
ask other turtles in-cone 6 60 [set seen? true]
```

only "detects" turtles if their xy is within the cone. They are basically points without dimensions. Is there an easy way to make a turtle of size 20 be much more "visible" than one of size 2? I've searched this and the yahoo group for answers and didn't find what I was looking for... maybe I'm not searching for the right terms... I'm new to programming and netlogo and everything so I'm probably missing something obvious here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is nothing built-in for this, nothing obvious. The math involved is somewhat hairy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Hmm... maybe something like "if the points in front or behind the turtles xy along the heading line and at distances less than 1/2 size fall within the cone...." that seems computationally intensive... I'll probably have to figure out some other way... :\